# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException after upgrade from hibernate 3 to hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, migration

I have an update process to update database using hibernate. The following is part of my code:

```
CUser cUser;
cUser = cManager.findUserDetailById(userId);

// here is some logic to update cUser detail.

// update db
hibernate.merge( cUser );
```

And I autowired my hibernate as follow:

```
@Autowired
protected HibernateTemplate hibernate;
```

And here is the way I declare my hibernate bean:

```
@Bean
  public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
  }
```

This is working fine when during hibernate 3. However, after I upgrade to hibernate 5, it will hit following error:

```
2018-08-02 11:19:59,828 ERROR [com.common.ui.extension.ExceptionHandler] (default task-12) Exception occurred: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1126)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$22.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:760)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:341)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:309)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.merge(HibernateTemplate.java:756)
```

I found that the `checkWriteOperationAllowed` method in hibernate 3 and hibernate 5 is different. But still not understand what is the purpose of this changes. Can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set flush mode for session, eg:

```
@Before
public void sessionInitMethod(){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
}
```

Comment: Is it ok if we manually change the flushMode? My concern is why hibernate 5 throw me exception, but hibernate 3 no problem.

Comment: @Panadol maybe hibernate change default flush policy. need to rtfm